# Excepciones con una cadena y sus valores

Tags: java, excepciones

quedria poder hacer uso de las excepciones pidiendo datos por consola y que la cadena que introduzca me analize si hay algun caracter que no es alfanumerico.

En cuanto encuentre un caracter no alfanumerico que pare.

Codigo:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ActivitatEx3a {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        boolean var = false;
        System.out.println("Entra una cadena: ");
        String entradaTeclado = "";
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner entradaEscaner = new Scanner (System.in);
        entradaTeclado = entradaEscaner.nextLine (); 
            for(int i = 0; i < entradaTeclado.length(); ++i) {
                char caracter = entradaTeclado.charAt(i);
                if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(caracter)) {
                        System.out.println("no alfa");
                }
            }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Es mejor evitar el uso de excepciones cuando es posible. Idealmente, el uso de excepciones debería reservarse para situaciones realmente excepcionales, porque vienen con un cierto costo. En tu caso, no veo que lo necesites.

Comment: Bueno pero aunque lo ideal sea evitar usar las excepciones, como deberia hacerlo?

Comment: ......`return;`

Answer (score 0):

No veo porque evitar excepciones. Puede ser costoso, pero depende del programa. En el caso del que muestra, no lo veo nada caro. Pero respeto y entiendo el comentario.

En el caso, de querer usar excepción en tu ejemplo, yo separaría la validación de la lectura, en un método valida(String entrada), y tiraría IllegalArgumentException ya que sería la lógica a usar.

```
public static void valida(String entrada) { 
    if (entrada == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("entrada nula");
    }
     for(int i = 0; i < entradaTeclado.length(); ++i) {
            char caracter = entradaTeclado.charAt(i);
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(caracter)) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("carater ilegal:"+caracter);
            }
        }
}
```

Después cambiaría tu método main a algo así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
    boolean var = false;
    System.out.println("Entra una cadena: ");
    String entradaTeclado = "";
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner entradaEscaner = new Scanner (System.in);
    entradaTeclado = entradaEscaner.nextLine (); 
    try {
        valida(entradaTeclado);
        System.out.println("entrada correcta:"+entradaTeclado);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("error en entrada:"+e.getMessage();
    }       
}
```

Espero este ejemplo te sirva. Saludos!